# Ajax Image gallery / Open, Close Window Effect

Tags: ajax, image, dynamic, gallery, photo

Can anyone point me in the direction of such a script? It should also be able to work when called into another ajax window. This is the type of gallery i am going for:

http://dageniusmarketer.com/DigitalWonderland/pages/DemoGalleryExample.html

It should go on this page:

dageniusmarketer.com/DigitalWonderland/

Portfolio section.

This script should be real simple to use with minimal extra files to make it work. I also should be able to just drop images in a gallery folder and it populates the gallery automatically with thumbnails....I shouldnt have to write code for each image in my html. Should be all dynamic.

---

I also would like to know how I could go about a window effect where every time I open up a new section via my navigation, the window shrinks closed with the old content, then expands open with the new content. the window effect should be vertical (top to bottom shrink into center, expand from center top to bottom)

Please Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is one of my personal favorite javascript libraries (along with 99% of this site apparently!)

But it will have a learning curve, as your requirements seem pretty specific, and you will have to read some documentation to pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

Try Spry from Adobe. They have a very similar demo. Also, the other common frameworks for this would be prototype/scriptaculous, dojo, mootools, jquery. In many cases they have extensions that would provide the exact thing you are looking for. For example, try
shadowbox extension which is framework agnostic. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Imago looks promising:

http://imago.codeboje.de/

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the very awesome-looking [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools) library today. Meets your "simple and minimal" requirements and could probably pull off what you've sketched, with just the "tooltips" and "scrollable" components.

> I also should be able to just drop images in a gallery folder and it populates the gallery automatically with thumbnails

My instinct is that you'd be better off writing server-side code to handle this part of your requirement.

Comment: Thanks alot guys, im going to look into all of your suggestions and let you know how it goes.